# Datetime interpretation issue

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
StartDate    FinishDate    Details
09/10/2013   11/10/2013    xxx
14/10/2013   13/10/2014    Taking a year off
```

Whilst editing this data I which to check the date ranges do not overlap.

I am running an SQL query from access via ado to do this; I am putting the dates entered into database format (ie 'mm/dd/yyyy'); This is the query I've got:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM MarkerAbsence 
WHERE PerID = 718 AND 
  ('10/09/2013' BETWEEN StartDate AND FinishDate OR 
   '10/11/2013' BETWEEN StartDate AND FinishDate)
```

If the data is valid, it should return zero records; however it doesnt it returns 1 (being the second listed record above) and therefore seems to be interpreting '10/11/2013' as dd/mm/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy.

Yet if I do this in SMO:

```
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '31/12/2008';
SELECT @datevar;
```

I get:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

While

```
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '12/31/2008';
SELECT @datevar;
```

returns

```
2008-12-31 00:00:00.0000000
```

So why am I having this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is data type of `StartDate` and `FinishDate` fields? Which RDBMS you are using? Is it SQL Server?

Comment: Are you sure it's matching the second record and not the first? I would think that 10/09/2013 would be between 10/09/2013 and 10/11/2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a query using MS Access, you need to delimit dates with `#` symbols, i.e.: #12/31/2008#.  If this won't work for whatever reason, it is best to use string dates in the `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format, as it will be recognized and is unambiguous.

You're probably getting this problem as MS is a US company, and the US uses mm/dd/yyyy format, so MS has defaulted much of their older software to treat dates as being in this format if at all possible, whereas you're probably in a country that uses - and have your PC's locality set to use - dd/mm/yyy format.  Since not all of MS' software follows this rule, you have this problem.

The solution is to use a string date format that is unambiguous, such as: `yyyy-mm-dd`, `mmm/dd/yyyy`, or `dd/mmm/yyyy` (where mmm returns a three-letter month such as `Dec`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; #s dont work if the backend is SQL server, only if it is access, but I'll have a play with the date format and see what happens.

Comment: MS being a US company has little to do with it - Access (since at least 2003) will use the regional settings of the PC.  SQL Server should use the appropriate format based on the language you selected at install time.

Comment: OK, you didn't put `MS-Access` or `SQL-Server` tags on your question, so it was a bit ambiguous whether you were talking about "SQL" as in "Structured Query Language" or as in "SQL Server".  `yyy-mm-dd` is ANSI-standard, so should be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

You are using dd/mm/yyyy formats for your date strings.  By default, without an explicit conversion, SQL is expecting date strings in the mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd format.  So either change your strings to match one of these formats or do this:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM MarkerAbsence 
WHERE PerID = 718 AND 
  (CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/09/2013', 103) BETWEEN StartDate AND FinishDate OR 
   CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/11/2013', 103) BETWEEN StartDate AND FinishDate)
```